# How to create typed JavaScript object using object initializer

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When I create an object using direct initialization and display it in the console, engine does not assign it any type (there is no surprise here, this is console thinks that displaying `Object` will not add any value), while when I use a constructor function, the type is assigned:

```
let obj1 = { d1: true, m1: function() { return 'MSG' } };
console.log(obj1);

let obj2 = new function SomeFunc() { };
obj2.anyField = 50;
console.log(obj2);
```

[image]

Is there any handy way to assign the type to an object right in the initializer without defining a function? Maybe there is something similar to `__proto__: { constructor: { name: 'abcd' } }`, that will work? Well, better something more simple.

Comment: Why? The whole type thing is useless

Comment: Just for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

An object has a type if and only if it has a constructor function. Therefore, within the bounds of your question (`without defining a function`) the only way to assign a type to an object is to give it a constructor function that has already been defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a named function to `obj1.__proto__.constructor`.

I don't think you can do it in the object literal, because the `__proto__` properties have to be merged into the normal prototype.

```js
let obj1 = { d1: true, m1: function() { return 'MSG' }};
obj1.__proto__.constructor = function AnotherFunc() {};
console.log(obj1);
```